# Error in "SyliusCurrencyBundle"

Tags: sylius

I installaled all sylius project in a an installed symfony project after all nicely configurated i got this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to
Sylius\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Templating\Helper\CurrencyHelper::__construct( )
must be an instance of
Sylius\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Templating\Helper\MoneyHelper,
instance of Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\Templating\Helper\MoneyHelper given, 
called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\de_\ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php
on line 5534 and defined in
C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Templating\Helper\CurrencyHelper.php line 38
```

when i run to homepage.
Can everyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too, it seems you have to declare the MoneyBundle BEFORE the Currency

```
//AppKernel.php

new Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\SyliusMoneyBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\SyliusCurrencyBundle(),
```